# What is the difference between `bower install foundation` and `foundation new MY_PROJECT`

Tags: sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation, gulp, bower

On the foundation [github](https://github.com/zurb/foundation) page the recommended way to install foundation is `bower install foundation` yet in their [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html) they suggest using `foundation new MY_PROJECT`. On the documentation page the first method is only listed under the "using a task runner" section. Both methods give different file structures. Are both ways correct and if so then why do they give different file structures.

Comment: This appears to be one of the many issues of Foundation: https://mattwilcox.net/web-development/trying-zurb-foundation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked a little more into it:

1. If you type `bower install foundation` you download the Foundation library as an asset to your existing project. There you have to take care of including the right files, setting up the build pipeline and wiring all up to your project. This is particularly good if you already have an opinion on how projects should be structured and integrated into your production pipeline / continuous integration.
2. Say that you want to create an entirely new project and have no starting conditions whatsoever. This project should not be "your project using Foundation" but "a Foundation project" inheriting all the opinions Zurb has on creating projects. If you are up for this road, then `foundation new project` is the way to go. This sets up all the assets, dependencies and build-chains for you. Actually this setup might even include the `foundation` bower component you would install otherwise. You will not have to worry about anything, but you will have a lot more to learn if you want to change things.

Comment: great answer I think that's it thanks. I'm doing a wordpress theme using underscores so I think it's the bower install foundation option I need to use, but there's a lot of connecting to do ... found this video doing just that in case it helps someone else on that front https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=De6H0eFrfvY